# Sql objects spell checker

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am just wondering that whether there is any utility which can help in determining the spelling mistakes in sql objects.

I can only think of getting information of all the sql objects and the save them in any other system (e.g. excel file) and then run a spell checker on it.

I am looking forward for a better way for this, like any plugin for MSSQL.

Comment: do you mean a syntax checker?

Comment: I mean to say like you have a column name in your table which has an spelling mistake like a column name like "word_longth" which should be "word_length" if we follow en-US dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spell check functionality built in Office as CLR function. Example see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa537153%28v=office.11%29.aspx

To use this, you need MS Word to be installed on server side.